# JavaScript Vanilla - Dependency Injection

Tags: javascript, angular, toastr

I've got an application using AngularJS and a file called 'util.js' where I use some useful functions which are shared through all application.

I have a 'module' injected in Angular called toastr (mesages to the users), I want to configure a confirm mesage in the file util.js, but to do so, I have to inject 'toastr' into the IFFE function, does anyone know how I can do that?

Thanks in advance

It's my controller:

```
function ClienteViewController($scope toastr) {

$scope.mensagemConfirmacao = function(codigo){
    utilJs.showConfirmDialog(id, otherFunction)
}
```

And it's my util.js file:

```
let utilJs = (function(){
  return {
    formatDateIntoString : function(string){
        return string.split('T')[0];
    }, 

    formatHourIntoString : function(string){
        return string.split('T')[1].split(".").splice(0, 1).toString();
    },

    showConfirmDialog: function(codigo, callback){
      html = `<br/><br/><button type='button' id='confirmationRevertYes' class='btn btn-default'>Sim</button>
      <button type='button' class='btn btn-default'>Não</button>`

      toastr.warning(html,
      'delete item?',
      {
          allowHtml: true,
          progressBar: true,
          preventDuplicates : true,
          positionClass: "toast-top-center",
          closeButton: false,
          onShown: function (toast) {
              document.querySelector("#yesButton").addEventListener('click', function(){
                callback(codigo);
              });
            }
      });
    }


  }
})();
```

Comment: `($scope toastr)` well that is wrong. Are you missing the comma in the actual code?

Comment: @epascarello, No, I am not ...I formated in english in order to post here and forgot to insert the coma, the toastr is loaded successfully, I just needed to inject into into the IFFE function

Comment: `function ClienteViewController($scope toastr)` <-- so add the comma

Comment: So the issue is the external.js file does not see toastr

Comment: do you know if there is a way to make the external.js sees toastr?